# React native how to store language in AsyncStorage and change the app language?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make a simple React Native app. For the start there is one default language, there is a button, by clicking on it changing the language and reloads the app with the new language. The idea is to store that language in the AsyncStorage (@react-native-async-storage/async-storage).

Here is my cache.js:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import moment from 'moment';

const prefix = 'cache';
const expiryInMinutes = 5;

const store = async (key, value) => {
    try {
        const item = {
            value,
            timestamp: Date.now()
        }
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(prefix + key, JSON.stringify(item));
    } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error);
    }
}

const get = async (key) => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(prefix + key);
        const item = JSON.parse(value);

        if(!item) return null;
        if(isExpired(item)) {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem(prefix + key);
            return null;
        }
        return item.value;
    } catch(error) {
        // console.log(error);
    }
}

const isExpired = (item) => {
    const now = moment(Date.now());
    const storedTime = item.timestamp;
    return now.diff(storedTime, 'minutes') > expiryInMinutes;
}

export default { store, get };
```

and here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';
import i18n from './app/locales/locales';
import cache from './app/utility/cache';

export default function App() {
  // When a value is missing from a language it'll fallback to another language with the key present.
  i18n.fallbacks = true;
  i18n.locale = 'de';
  cache.get('lang').then(function(result) {
    if(result) {
      i18n.locale = result;
      // console.log("New lang " + result);
    }
  });
  const handleRestart = async () => {
    // console.log("Storing lang: ");
    // console.log("Reseting lang: ");
    cache.store("lang", 'en');
    // console.log(cache.get('lang'));
    // console.log("Hmm");
    // console.log(i18n.locale);
    await Updates.reloadAsync();
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{i18n.t('hello')}</Text>
      <Button title="Restart" onPress={handleRestart} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

It starts in German, when I press the button it stores the English, but it doesn't change the application language. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wrote a blog post about it. It also uses i18n-js, moment
https://stefan-majiros.com/blog/implementing-react-native-localization-like-a-pro/

Answer (score 0):

I'm think UI is not getting updated, because react re-renders only if props or state gets changed. Since non of those changed, you are not going to see any updated on UI.

try something like this

```
const [lang, setLang] = React.useState(langValueFromStorage);
const handleRestart = () => {
 
cache.get('lang').then(function(result) {
    if(result) {
      i18n.locale = result;
      setLang(result)
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I have found a solution though it looks a bit hacky. **i18n.js**:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import en from './src/localization/en/en.json';
import uz from './src/localization/uz/uz.json';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en,
  },
  uz: {
    translation: uz,
  },
};

const getDefaultLang = async () => {
  const storedLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('lang');

  return i18n
    .use(initReactI18next) 
    .init({
      resources,
      lng: storedLang ? storedLang : 'uz', 

      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, 
      },

      fallbackLng: ['uz', 'en'],
    });
};

export default getDefaultLang();
```

2. There is also a [plugin](https://dev.to/ramonak/react-native-internationalization-with-i18next-568n) used for detecting lang from asyncstorage which I have just found